# Does string.Format add extra quotes to value

Tags: c#, string-concatenation, string.format

I discovered that whenever I use this method string.Format(), it adds extra quotes and backslash to my variable value.

```
string value = string.Format("sample {0}", someText);
```

**On VS Watch**, I see this result:

```
"sample \"blah\""
```

**In Text Visualizer**, I get this:

```
sample "blah"
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't get this?

```
"sample blah"
```

Please note: *I have a workaround already which is `string.Replace("\"","")` but I just want to know where the extra quotes was added.*

Comment: That doesn't happen here.. Your `sometext` variable must contain `"brah"` as a value.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm 100% sure, in your context, sometext contains the extra quotes.

```
string.Format("sample {0}", "blah")
```

returns "sample blah"

Comment: @Oluwafemi No problem! Sometimes, the smallest bugs cause the biggest headaches  :)

Answer (score 2):

This relates only to VS Debugging. It´s not ACTUALLY adding anything to that string. VS is just escaping strings, nothing to worry about or to handle with.

EDIT: To get `sample blah` (without ANY quotes) instead of `sample "blah"` you need to replace the quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.Replace("\"", "");
```

Now within VS Debugger you see the following: `"sample blah"` whilst within a text-file e.g. you´ll see `sample blah`

Answer (score 0):

It shows your `sometext` contains "blah" instead of blah.
That is why `\"`  is appearing during debug.

Answer (score 0):

This `string.Format` doesn't add *anything* to any string at all.

The difference is how you can see your string in a Visual Studio and in a Text Visualizer. Since because `"` is an [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) character, you need to use it as `\"` in your code part.

As far as I know, these escape sequence characters are legacy from C language standard.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

> Can anyone tell me why I can't get this?
>
> "sample blah"

Because you didn't do *anything* to get this string in your example. Your string doesn't have an escaped `"` character at start or in the end. You can use escape them in your string.format like;

```
string someText = "blah";
string value = string.Format("\"sample {0}\"", someText);
```

Result will be;

```
"sample blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string doesn't have any quotes in it.
If you want the string to contain quotes you need to add quotes to the format string.

string foo = "foo"
foo has the value foo

string foo = "\"foo\""
foo has the value "foo"